# react-navigation TabNavigator render only first tab

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

i am developing react-native application, and i am using TabNavigator (react-navigation) with 2 simple Tabs contain login-screen (both tabs have the same screen). the 1st tab always shows up but the 2nd tab won't show.

i see no errors.
i run it on ios simulator (iPhone x, ios 11)

```
const LoginStack = StackNavigator({
    Login: {
        screen: SignIn,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Sign In' //strings('screens.SignIn.title'),
        },
    },
}, {
 headerMode: 'screen',
});

export const SignedInTabs = TabNavigator
  Orders: {
      screen: LoginStack, //OrdersStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'login', //strings('tabs.Orders'),
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => ( <Icon name = "list" color = {tintColor} size = {28} />),
        },
  },
  Account: {
        screen: LoginStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'login', //strings('tabs.Account'),
            tabBarIcon: ({tintColor}) => ( <Icon name = "account-circle" color = {tintColor} size = {28} />),
        },
  },
 }, {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#FFF',
        activeBackgroundColor: colors.primaryTheme
    },
});
```

react-native version: 0.51.0

react-navigation version: 1.0.0-beta.27

node version: 6.11.0

npm version: 3.10.10

[image: 1st tab shows up well]

[image: 2nd tab didn't show up]

EDIT (May-26-18):

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1627#issuecomment-368323254

robvolk comment solved my issue.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. It looks like its a bug with the newest react-navigation release? According to this thread (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3586) a downgrade to react-navigation@1.0.3 will fix the problem. I downgraded and successfully fixed the issue.

I was tearing out my hair for 2 days on this one.

Comment: downgrade did not help me :(